# Spring AOP - I want to apply the pointcut to a class from a library

Tags: java, spring, aop

I'm trying to use Spring AOP to add logging to methods coming from a third party library. So there is a class, ProxyServlet, that is being used by my Spring Boot application, and I just want to apply logging to it.

```
@Pointcut("within(com.common.httpproxy.ProxyServlet)")
    private void proxyServlet() {}

    @Before("proxyServlet()")
    public void testLog() {
        log.info("THIS IS WORKING");
    }
```

This is just some test AOP code right here. I know that my Spring AOP is set up, because I can get log output for any classes included in my codebase. However, I can't get log output for any classes from a third party library, like the ProxyServlet.

Is there anything I can do to get this AOP advice to work?

Comment: Are the external library classes spring beans?

Comment: @daniu yes. (I am not the OP but I have the same question)

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate the class containing this code with:

```
@Aspect
@Component
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ProxyServer instance is a bean, you can achieve it by defining an aspect for the logging something like below.

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {    
        @Before(execution(* the.package.ProxyServlet.*(..)))
        public void loggingAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint){
            System.out.println("Started loggingAdvice on method="+joinPoint.toString());
            System.out.println("The aruguments are =" + Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
        }

    }
```

Please note that it is not necessary to have a custom point-cut like @LoggingAdvice here and annotate the target method using it (I am pointing it because you mentioned that the class is in third party library by which means you are expressing the concern that you may not be able to annotate meothod(s) with a pointcut) . Custom point-cuts are useful when you define widely applicable Aspects and limit the application of it to certain joint pints (thru the custom pointcut)
As your target is a single class and is third party library, you are good without a custom point-cut but with an aspect specifically targeting the required class.
The above define Aspect will be executed for every method defined in the ProxyBean class.